# How to style the Google Colab's markdown with CSS?

Tags: python, html, css, markdown, google-colaboratory

I can write down the following code and get the desired result in a "code" cell in Google Colab:

```
%%html
<style>
  body {background-color: #EAF6F6;}
</style>
<body>
<h1> Alireza </h1>
</body>
```

[image]

Would you tell me how can I reproduce this in a Markdown cell? Generally how can one use internal css styling in the markdown in Colab?

Comment: Styling markdown cells isn't supported. If you need custom styling of text, your best bet is to hide the code and produce HTML output has you've done.